# The database is correctly structured to handled the scenario when "all_participant" is "0"?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design

I have a context where I have a form for a user do a registration in a congress. And there are two different contexts: when "all_participant" is "1" and when "all_participant" is "0" in the congresses table.

**When all_participant is "1":**

- if "all_participant" is "1" in the congress table, and the user is doing a registration in some ticket types and none ticket type have custom questions associated, in the registration form is necessary to collect only the name and surname about each participant that the user is registering
- if "all_participant" is "1" and the user is doing a registration in some ticket types that have custom questions associated is necessary to collect the answer to that custom questions for each participant that is being registered in that ticket types that have that custom questions

To better when "all_participants" is 1 in the congress table:

[image]

When the user click "Go to step 2" in the registration form, is inserted an entry in the Registrations table, an entry for each participant in Participants table and entries in the answers table relative to the answers to the custom questions. So the database stays like below when the user click in "Go to step 2" in the registration form:

```
Registrations table: 
id       status        congress_id        main_participant_id
7          C              1                         1   
Participants table:
id   registration_id      ticket_type_id        name        surname
12        7                     1                  John         W
13        7                     2                   Jake        Y
Answers table:
id    participant_id     question_id      answer
2           12              1               0002
3            13             1               0003
```

**When all_participant is "0":**

My doubt is about how to store the information when "all_participants" is "0". So the user John that is doing the registration selected 2 tickets, one ticket of the ticket type "tt1" and other of the ticket type "tt2", and the ticket type "tt1" has 1 custom question associated and now "all_participants" is "0", which means that is not necessary to collect info about each participant, is only necessary to use the info of the auth user to do the registration.

But if there are custom questions is necessary that the auth user (the user that is doing the registration) answer these custom questions, but if "all_participant" is "0" only the user that is doing the registration needs to answer these questions, so for example if the user selected two tickets and 1 or more have some custom questions associated, in the registration form, besides the user selected 2 tickets in the registration form it will only appear once the custom question(s) and not twice because is only for the user that is doing the registration to answer (because "all_participants" is "0"). So in this scenario when user clicks in the "Go to step 2" in the registration form the database stays like:

```
Registrations table:
id       status        congress_id        main_participant_id
10         C                1                   1   

Participants table: (name and surname and blank because when "all_participant" is "0" is not necessary to collect name and surname of each participant)
id   registration_id      ticket_type_id        name        surname
18        10                     1                          
19        10                     2                   
Answers table:
id    participant_id     question_id      answer
4           18              1               0002
```

**Doubt:**

My doubt is if you know if this is structured correctly because as it is it seems that is not possible to know to which user the answers belong
**when** "all_participant" is "0" and there are custom questions in 1 or more ticket types selected by the user. Because the ansers table only have the participant_id which in this case is "18" but the user that did the registration is the user in the users table with id "1".

The main_participant_id in the registrations table is the id of the user in the users table that did the registration which allow to know which user did the registration.

To better illustrate the 3 possible scenarios when "all_participant" is 0:

[image]

Relationships relevant for the question:

```
1 to many between Congresses and Registrations
1 to many between Congresses and TicketTypes
1 to many between Registrations and Participants
1 to many between TicketTypes and Participants
1 to many between Participants and Answers
1 to many between Questions and Answers
Many to Many between TicketTypes and Questions
1 to many between Congresses and Questions
```

Relevant models for the question:

```
// Congress model
class Congress extends Model
{ 
    // A conference has one creator
    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'congress_id');
    }
}
// User model

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function congresses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Congress', 'user_id');
    }

    // A user can register in many conferences
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','main_participant_id');
    }
}

// Registration model
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // a registration can have many participants
    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

}

// Participant Model

class Participant extends Model
{
    // a participant belongs to a registration
    public function registration(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}

// Ticket Type model
class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions')->withPivot(['required']);;
    }
}


// Question model

class Question extends Model
{

    public function ticket_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
}

// Answer model
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Question');
    }
    public function participant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Participant');
    }
}
// TicketTypeQuestion model
class RegistrationTypeQuestion extends Model
{

}
```

To register the user and other participants that he can register, in both scenarios: "all_participant" as "1" and "all_participant" as "0", I have the register() method for now like :

```
public function register(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
        $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
        $user = Auth::user();

        $rules = [];
        $messages = [];

        if(isset($request->participant_question_required)) {
            $messages = [
                'participant_question.*.required' => 'Fill all mandatory fields',
                'participant_name.*.required' => 'Fill all name fields.',
                'participant_surname.*.required' => 'Fill all surname fields.',
            ];

            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255'; 
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
            }
        }

        if($allParticipants){

            $rules["participant_name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
            $rules["participant_surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';

        }
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors =  json_decode($errors);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $errors
            ], 422);
        }

        if($validator->passes()) {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);

            $participants = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
                $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
                $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => $name,
                    'surname' => $surname,
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]

                ]);
            }

            if (isset($request->participant_question))
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                    $answer = Answer::create([
                        'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                        'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                    ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the idea of "main participant"?  Specifically, if John X is the person getting the tickets on behalf of the group, I don't understand how it's invalid to regard his Id in the Answers table as 18.  Under what context is it 1?  Or maybe I should put it like this; in your "when all_participant 0" scenario, are we talking about three people, or two?  I wonder if you're not making a good enough distinction between the concept of "user" vs. "participant".  Another possibility might be to consider "participant" and "main" more of a user-*role* than an entity unto itself.

Comment: The main_participant_id in the registrations table is the id of the user in the users table (a user can create congresses and can register in congresses). So for example in the question example the main_participant_id "1" in the registrations table is the id of the user "John X" in the users table. It means that this user did the registration. The registration can have multiple participants but it was this user that did the registration.

Comment: And the user that does the registration needs to have an account in the system the other participants that the user that does the registration can register are just names and surnames that are stored in the participants table, are not users of the system.

Comment: When all_participant is "0" it means that is not necessary collect info of all participants that the user is registering. For example if the user in the previous page selected that he wanted 1 ticket of the ticket type "tt1" and 1 ticket of the ticket type "tt2" is because he wants two tickets for two persons. All_participant as "0" only means that in the registration form it will not appear two name and surname fields for the user to fill in because is not necessary to collect info of all participants is jsut necessary to collect info of the user that is doing the registration.

Comment: So when_all participant is "0" is used the info of the auth user  to do the registration, and its only necessary the user to fill in some fields if he selected some ticket type that has associated custom questions. But if all_participant is "0" only the auth user, the user that is doing the registration, needs to fill in that custom questions, so the custom questions should appear only once and not twice, even if both tickets have that custom question associated, because is only necessary to collect info of the user that is doing the registration when "all_participant" is "0".

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like your Answers table needs an awareness of in what capacity the answer-er was acting.  Please see my comment, as thorough as you were in describing the situation, I'm still a little unclear on some things.  But at the moment, my hunch is that your data-structure is misinterpreting the idea of "main" or "participant" as a unique person as opposed to a role that a given person may carry.

I think what you need are tables that look like this:

```
Table        | Relationship        | Table
-------------------------------------------------
Users        | one-to-many         | Participants
Groups       | one-to-many         | Participants
Participants | many-to-many        | Roles
             | (Participant_Roles) |
Answers      | one-to-one          | Participant_Roles (replace your Answers.participant_id with this)
Answers      | one-to-one          | Question
Tickets      | many-to-many        | Question
             | (Ticket_Questions)  |
```

Your roles might be things like "main" and "attendee".  So the trick here would be giving your Answer a reference to not just the person, but in what capacity they were acting at the time.

Comment: Text scenario to explain better: For example the user John is in the congress details page of the congres "Congress Test". In this page it appears the ticket types available and John selects that he wants 1 ticket of  the ticket type "tt1" and 1 ticket of the ticekt type "tt2". Now John is redirected to page with the congress registration form. If all participant is "1", in the form it will appear two name and two surname fields. So John will fill in his name, his surname and the name and surname of the other person that he is registering.

Comment: If for example both ticket types selected by John have custom quesions associated like "Whats your phone?" it will appear in the regisration form two fields "Whats your phine?"" for John answer his phone and the phone of the other person. If only only one ticket type has 1 or more custom questions associated, for example only ticket type "tt1" has one custom question, for example "Whats your phone?", in the registration form it will appaer only once "Whats your phone?" field for John to answer.

Comment: If both "tt1" and "tt2" dont have any custom question associated John only needs do fill in the name and surname of each participant.

Comment: If all_participant is "0" and  both "tt1" and "tt2" dont have any custom question associated John dont needs to enter any information because is used his auth informatio to do the registration. So in the registration form John only needs to click "Next". If 1 or both selected tickets have 1 or more custom questions in the registration form it will appear that custom questions but only once even if John is registerting 10 participants only John needs to answer the custom questions that exist for the selected tickets, beause is only necesary to collect info of the user that did the regisration.